# Custom notification sound , android Oreo?

Tags: android, uri, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I want to set a custom notification sound from a raw mp3 or wav file in my app.
Below is my code

```
private void sendMyNotification(String message) {
    Intent intent;
    if (sharedPreferences.getBoolean(SPConstants.IS_LOGGED_IN, false)) {
        intent = new Intent(this, ActivityNotification.class);
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(this, ActivitySplash.class);
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.panic);
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100, 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);
    }
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

The panic audio file resides in res->raw.
I have tried to use both mp3 and wav formats of the sound but nothing seems to work to set the notification sound.
I am currently testing on Pixel 2 OS 8.1.

Any suggestions what could be the issue?

Comment: Hmmm. I was facing the similar issue. The only solutions that I have found were to give a possibility to set it by OS notification channel settings. It is because of once you create a notification channel you cannot change its settings programmatically (but maybe I have done it wrong). If you will find any other solution I would love to know how to fix this.

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński below answer by Khaled does seems to work only if you have not setContentIntent.

Comment: I will definitely check it, but in my case, I use `setContentIntent`. Thanks for notifying me :)

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński Yes that's the same issue with me as well. I am also using setContentIntent but does not work in that case.

Comment: hmmm, I am just wondering if this is not an OS bug. `setContentIntent` has nothing to do with notification sound/vibration settings in my opinion. I will take a look at that because this might be a thing that should be reported to the Google

Comment: @PatrykJabłoński keep me posted for the same

Comment: make sure to UNINSTALL the APP.

Answer (score 50):

- Tested blow code and worked with me as expected.
- Add Content intent and that still working without any issues with me.

  ```
  private void sendMyNotification(String message) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

  Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.correct_answer);
  NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "CH_ID")
          .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
          .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
          .setContentText(message)
          .setAutoCancel(true)
          .setSound(soundUri)
          .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

  NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
  if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

      if(soundUri != null){
          // Changing Default mode of notification
          notificationBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
          // Creating an Audio Attribute
          AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                  .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                  .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
                  .build();

          // Creating Channel
          NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel("CH_ID","Testing_Audio",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
          notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri,audioAttributes);
          mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
      }
  }
  mNotificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
  }
  ```

**Update**

- You may need uninstall the app to alter sound settings, Check out these **[link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels)** for more details.

Comment: if you set content intent to notification builder then this code does not work

Comment: @WISHY Updated my answer with `setContentIntent(pendingIntent)` and still working with me, You may need uninstall the app to alter sound settings, Check out these [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#ManageChannels) for more details.

Comment: @KhaledLela I am getting this problem : https://stackoverflow.com/q/53913251/1318946

Comment: @KhaledLela How to do this for android 10

Comment: The uninstall part seems to be crucial - without that it didn't work for me on a couple of phones

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling app helped me a lot, thanks

Comment: i was doing what you told above but was not working until reinstalled the app, thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem works with uninstall but I have 3 different notification sound and I want to change programmatically, how can I do that without telling use to uninstall the app ?

Answer (score 4):

Simple answer:

```
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse(
                         "android.resource://" + 
                         getApplicationContext().getPackageName() +
                         "/" + 
                         R.raw.push_sound_file);

AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
            .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
            .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_ALARM)
            .build();

// Creating Channel
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("YOUR_CHANNEL_ID",
                                                      "YOUR_CHANNEL_NAME",
                                                      NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
channel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);

((NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE))
                                           .createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
```

Answer (score 1):

Late but might be helpful to some one,   just add below line in your NotificationCompat.Builder() instance:

```
.setSound("your sound uri",AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION)
```

Note:
As  `NotificationCompat.Builder()` is backward compatible , so  `AudioAttributes` etc in notification channel is not required