# Different notification sound not working in Oreo

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am facing some **Notification** related issue in **Oreo** Version only. I follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029731/1318946) and successfully got custom sound after uninstall/install the app as he has suggested.

Now problem is that I want to use two custom sound in my app, For that, I have code like:

```
private void sendNotification(NotificationBean notificationBean) {
    String textTitle = notificationBean.getTitle();
    String alert = notificationBean.getMessage().getAlert();
    int orderId = notificationBean.getMessage().getOrderId();
    String notificationType = notificationBean.getMessage().getNotificationType();
    String sound = notificationBean.getMessage().getSound();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri soundUri;

    if (notificationType.equals("Pending"))
        soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);
    else
        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle(textTitle)
            .setContentText(alert)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(getString(R.string.app_name), name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setSound(soundUri, attributes);

        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(101, mBuilder.build());
}
```

If I get `notificationType = "Pending"` then I want to use custom sound, otherwise `DEFAULT` sound but Here It is playing that sound which is played first-time (When I receive notification first time.).

I am getting this problem in OREO only. In all other devices its working fine.

Any help? Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Problem:** 
It seems Notification Channel issue.

**Solution:**
Either you should create separate channel, or you should delete your own channel.

**Strategy:**
**1) Create separate channel:**
You may select this strategy if you want to persist ***multiple channels*** along with ***various*** configuration for your app. 
To create separate channel, just provide unique channel ID while creating it.
i.e.:

```
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(uniqueChannelId, name, importance);
```

**2) Delete your existing channel and re-create it:**
You may select this strategy if you want to persist ***only one channel*** along with ***updated*** configuration for your app.

To delete your own channel and re-create it, following may work fine:

```
NotificationManager mNotificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);

NotificationChannel existingChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(channelId);

//it will delete existing channel if it exists
if (existingChannel != null) {
mNotificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
}
//then your code to create channel
NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, name, importance);
```

Comment: Thank you Mehul, I got hint from your answer. I have created two channel id for different sound and its working perfectly.

Comment: @PratikButani I am glad to help. I have added some more details which can help in deciding the strategy based on requirements.

Comment: If the channel is re-created after deleting it, the system takes in the pre-saved configurations for that channel Id, that is even if you set a new sound file while recreating the channel, it will take in the previous sound file attached to it. Is there any configuration setup step, I might be missing

Comment: You are right @Tulika system retains its configuration from the previously saved channel. So if you want to change the notification sound then you have recreate notification channel with different channel id. Please follow this blog for more https://rathorerahul586.medium.com/android-change-notification-sound-93eb4fd4ece5

Answer (score 5):

I got hint to solve my problem from @Mehul Joisar's answer.

As he wrote:

> Either you should create separate channel, or you should delete your
>   own channel.

I have created two separate channels for different sounds.

> As I think, we cant change Notification Channel settings after once we
>   have created channel. We must have to remove and create new or else We
>   have to create separate channels for different settings.

Here I am sharing full code to help others.

```
private void sendNotification(NotificationBean notificationBean) {
    String textTitle = notificationBean.getTitle();
    String alert = notificationBean.getMessage().getAlert();
    int orderId = notificationBean.getMessage().getOrderId();
    String notificationType = notificationBean.getMessage().getNotificationType();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NavigationDrawerActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Uri soundUri;
    String channelName;

    if (notificationType.equals("Pending")) {
        channelName = getString(R.string.str_chef);
        soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sound);
    }
    else {
        channelName = getString(R.string.str_customer);
        soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelName)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
            .setContentTitle(textTitle)
            .setContentText(alert)
            .setSound(soundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);

    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.app_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.app_name);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);

        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();

        channel.enableLights(true);
        channel.enableVibration(true);
        channel.setSound(soundUri, attributes);

        // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
        // or other notification behaviors after this
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
    notificationManager.notify(101, mBuilder.build());
}
```

> NOTE: Must uninstall your app first and then test with this code.

Thank you.