# Notification plays default sound instead of installed

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get Uri on one of system ringtone(user chouse it  by himself). and then this Uri is using in notification. But notification plays default sound instead of chosed by user. This is code for button which opens activity for choosing sound

```java
ringtone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
                intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
```

after this i am getting URI

```java
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == 5){
            uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
            ringtone.setText(uri.toString());
        }
    }
```

for example, Uri after choosing looks like this: CONTENT://MEDIA/INTERNAL/AUDIO/MEDIA/36
is it correct Uri?

and by clicking another button, notification should appear

```java
 music.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                Resources res = context.getResources();
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
                builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play25x25).setContentTitle("Title").setContentText("Text").setSound(uri).setChannelId("1");
                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);;
                NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("1", "name", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
                notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
            }
        });
```

aaand it appears, but with default system notification sound, not with installed by user 
Please help. What i am doing wrong? I thought, maybe i need any permissions in manifest?

Comment: check this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53930194/3633468

Answer (score 0):

Do you create your notification channel when app starts? In App's onCreate(). Like this

```
 channelId = getString(R.string.notification_chat_channel);
        channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                "Some channel name",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.push_sound);
        channel.setSound(uri, att);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
```