# Ionic 4 local notification sound not working in Oreo+

Tags: ionic-framework, audio, android-8.0-oreo, localnotification

I am building an Ionic 4 app and the Local Notification `sound` was working in Nougat, but is not working Oero.
Is just playing the default sound, and ignoring the `sound`

I have read here: 
https://distriqt.github.io/ANE-PushNotifications/m.FCM-GCM%20Payload

> Sounds on individual notifications were deprecated in Android O (API 26). You now have to set them on a channel.

[Different notification sound not working in Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53913251/different-notification-sound-not-working-in-oreo)

that Channel is necessary

```
 this.localNot.schedule({
      id: id,
      // channel: id, // IS NOT Possible to set
      title: title,
      text: 'Some text',
      sound: `file://assets/audio/mySOUNDFILE.mp3`,
      icon: 'file://assets/img/logo/favicon.png', // TODO resident Img,
      color: colour
    });
```

But Like I had not field "channel" available in ionic I set an issue here, but was close.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/19696

Do you have a suggestion how can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using this 
     "git+https://github.com/Steffaan/cordova-plugin-local-notifications.git",

home.ts

```
declare var cordova: Cordova;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home', ...
```

and to send notification

```
    cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
      id: Myid,
      title: tit,
      text: txt,
      priority: MyPriority,
      channel: 'MyChannel',
      sound: `file://assets/audio/${sound}.mp3`,
      foreground: true,
      lockscreen: true,
      vibrate: vib,
      wakeup: true,
    });
```

Where

```
      priority: MyPriority,
      channel: 'MyChannel',
```

must be different, for each different sound

in file /node_modules/@types/cordova/index.d.ts I set:

```
interface CordovaPlugins {
    notification: any;
...
}
```