# How To push Cloud Messaging With Sound?

Tags: android, audio, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have integrated my app with Fire base and when i send cloud messaging it comes with no voice can you please help me as i am a beginner .

and i Do not know which file should be edited .

```
{
"to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",

"notification" : {
  "body" : "great match!",
  "title" : "Portugal vs. Denmark",
  "icon" : "myicon",
  "sound" : "mySound"
}
```

}

Comment: This is how it will work :https://stackoverflow.com/a/53931291/1318946

Answer (score 0):

Use setSound() method to set your notification sound in your NotificationCompat.Builder

I use Kotlin, it will be like this

```
val defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION)
val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)  
            .setContentTitle(message.data["title"]) 
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message.data["body"]))
            .setContentText(message.data["body"])
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
```