# How to fix about no push message notification sounds and vibrations

Tags: android

I am android developer. No push message notification sounds and vibrations are generated. It was updated and distributed with API 26 and before that, notification sounds and vibrations were well generated (probably API 22). I want to know the cause and solution.

Comment: just check whether user has disabled sound and vibration for notifications for your app

Comment: Check out this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029731.
The thing is you have to create channel for notification/group of notification for devices that runs Oreo or higher version of android. And you can only set vibration and sound once for channel when you create it.